# "No Error." thrown on Membership.CreateUser

Tags: c#, asp.net-membership

I have a custom membership provider with create user method:

```
public override MembershipUser CreateUser(string username, string password, string email, string passwordQuestion, string passwordAnswer, bool isApproved, object providerUserKey, out MembershipCreateStatus status)
    {

        if ((RequiresUniqueEmail == true) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(GetUserNameByEmail(email)))
        {
            status = MembershipCreateStatus.DuplicateEmail;
            return null;
        }

        MembershipUser userMember = GetUser(username, true);
        if (userMember == null)
        {
            User user = new User();
            user.Name = username;
            user.Salt = user.GenerateSalt();
            user.Password = user.hashedpassword(password);
            user.Email = email;
            user.isApproved = isApproved;
            user.Register();
            status = MembershipCreateStatus.Success;
        }
        else
        {
            status = MembershipCreateStatus.DuplicateUserName;
        }

        return null;
    }
```

But when I try to use this method:

```
try
    {
        Membership.CreateUser(Name, Password, Mail);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Defaults.Error = ex;
    }
```

I get an exception {"No Error."}. 
However new user is created and there is no problem with log in and log out.

Comment: Awesome. Consider attaching a debugger and trying to capture said exception early - where does it come from? Also, shouldn't the MembershipUser be returned somewhere/somehow ..?

Comment: Couldn't find the error, because the exception was thrown only at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry! Stupid mistake..

```
return GetUser(username, true);
```

should be at the end and not

```
return null;
```